# Heroku is using the wrong requirements.txt when I try to git push my app

Tags: django, git, heroku

I'm trying to install a django app to Heroku for the first time.  I've been following tutorials and things were going fine until `git push heroku master`.  I get an error with postgrequl/psycopg2:

```
Collecting psycopg2==2.6.2 (from -r /tmp/build_9a1b9401a05f6186e32ef1f993bdd183/requirements.txt (line 10))
remote:          Downloading blah...blah../bc/psycopg2-2.6.2.tar.gz (376kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            running egg_info
remote:            creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
remote:            writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
remote:            writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
remote:            writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
remote:            writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
remote:            Error: could not determine PostgreSQL version from '10.5'
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-mu5yzi1s/psycopg2/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to django-randomizer.
```

I did some searches and I read where other people had problems because they had an older version of psycopg2.  So I edited my requirements.txt file to include `psycopg2-2.7.5`, which is the latest.  I think try `git push heroku master' again and I get the same error. The error references psycopg2-2.6.2.

I even deleted my app and started again, but when it came to the git push, I get the same error. At this time I think that git is in some state where it keeps trying to do the push that already failed. I'm not sure though.  Any ideas?

```
git reflog:
5fd142e (HEAD -> deployheroku, origin/deployheroku) HEAD@{0}: pull origin deployheroku: Fast-forward
df048a9 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{1}: reset: moving to HEAD^
5fd142e (HEAD -> deployheroku, origin/deployheroku) HEAD@{2}: commit: change settings and wsgi for heroku
df048a9 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to deployheroku
df048a9 (origin/master, origin/HEAD, master) HEAD@{4}: commit: restore local version
873d636 HEAD@{5}: commit: updated psycopg2 in requirements.txt
aebfe43 HEAD@{6}: commit: get files ready for heroku
6273553 HEAD@{7}: commit: removed old files
9b2c347 HEAD@{8}: commit: update with new app name
6b4103d HEAD@{9}: clone: from https://github.com/shmish/django-randomizer.git
```

My requirements.txt is:

```
certifi==2018.8.13
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.5.0
Django==2.0.8
django-allauth==0.36.0
django-filter==2.0.0
docopt==0.6.2
idna==2.7
oauthlib==2.1.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
python-decouple==3.1
python3-openid==3.1.0
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.19.1
requests-oauthlib==1.0.0
urllib3==1.23
whitenoise==4.0
yarg==0.1.9
```

Comment: I edited the question and included the requirements.txt

Comment: Is `psycopg2==2.7.5` in `master` or `deployheroku`? I clearly see `psycopg2==2.6.2`. Can you show us the result of `git show master:requirements.txt | grep psycopg2` and `git show deployheroku:requirements.txt | grep psycopg2`?

Comment: `$ git show deployheroku:requirements.txt | grep psycopg2
psycopg2==2.7.5`

Comment: `$ git show master:requirements.txt | grep psycopg2
psycopg2==2.6.2`

Comment: Are you not utilizing dj-database-url in your deployment?, I would also use psycopg2==2.7.1 and not run the latest version on Heroku. To be sure your requirements.txt file is being used for the latest attempt to deploy enter your changes to the file, the git add . the git commit -m 'changes to requirements.txt' and finally git push heroku master.

Comment: You also need to check over your code look at line 17 of your wsgi.py file for a typo.

Comment: This supports my suggestion for utilizing psycopg2==2.7.1  please read: https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/741

Comment: I had to git init and git push a new branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ git show master:requirements.txt | grep psycopg2
psycopg2==2.6.2
```

So you've deployed a wrong branch. Either deploy `deployheroku` or update `requirements.txt` in `master`.